# Cannot get selenium to select a button for me using xpath. What am I missing?

Tags: java, python, selenium, xpath

```
continue_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='button' and @class='primary button']")
continue_button.click();
```

for some reason this does not work. this is what i know about the button i am clicking on:
its in a div AND

```
<button class="primary button" type="button"></button>
```

that is all i have to work with. help? browser.find_element_by_id works great for other items on the same page so my driver and everything is working.

it loads the page, types in text into fields that i have setup and i want it to click continue button and it just stops and ends.

the original html:

```
<div class="GLHWMP-BMTC">

<span class="inlineBlock GLHWMP-BDUC">
    <button class="primary button" type="button"></button>
    <span class="GLHWMP-BPTC GLHWMP-BEUC"></span>
    <span class="GLHWMP-BPTC GLHWMP-BLTC"></span>
</span>
```

Comment: `this does not work` What exactly is happening?

Comment: Are you running selenium headless?

Comment: i am not sure, still new to this stumbling through.

Comment: Try with ==> 
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='button' and @class='primary button']")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of the element that you are trying to click is `<button>`.

So to begin with, you need to change `//input` to `//button`.

In addition, you don't have to use both the `class` attribute and the `type` attribute, unless that is the **only** combination that uniquely identifies the element. Otherwise, you may simply use the attribute that uniquely identifies the element (either the `class` attribute or the `type` attribute).

Comment: i need to specify the div class ... there are other buttons with these attributes

Comment: xpath=(//button[@type='button'])[2]     this is what selenium IDE is suggesting but the button is never clicked.

Comment: Well, if you want to get further help on this, then please provide the URL of the web-page that you are trying to control, or at least the relevant piece of HTML. I cannot guess what the HTML document looks like.

Comment: added original HTML to main post

Comment: ah hah! needed to use descendant: ("//div[@class='GLHWMP-BMTC']/descendant::button[@type='button']")